# Do UX guy needs to be good at making designs using Photoshop and converting them into HTML, CSS?

Tags: ux-field, frontend-development

Do UX guy needs to be good at making designs using Photoshop and converting them into HTML, CSS? Or these are job of Graphic/web designer and front-end guy?

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. It's a pretty common question. Answers vary, but, in general, no, one does not have to be a graphic designer nor front end developer to be good at UX design, but is absolutely helps if you are.

Comment: aye, it's a common question for uxers

Comment: More technical knowledge will never hurt as it enables smoother communication and greater trust between designers and technical members of the team.